# Problems reading squid logs for accounting

Tags: javascript, squid

I was trying to read access.log from squid but my algorithm is reading much more bytes compared to sarg. Where am I wrong?

On same data session
SARG - 57,58MB
My Algorithm - 900MB

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cron = require('node-cron');
const axios = require('axios').default;

cron.schedule("*/5 * * * * *", async function() {
    let processedLogs = [];
    const lastRead = fs.readFileSync('last.txt', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    const data = fs.readFileSync('access.log', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    const toRead = data.substring(lastRead);
    if(toRead !== ""){
        fs.unlinkSync('last.txt');
        fs.writeFileSync('last.txt', (data.length).toString());
        const linesLog = data.split("\n");
        for(let b = 0; b <= linesLog.length-1; b++){
            if(linesLog[b] !== ""){
                const lineList = linesLog[b].split(" ").filter((str) => str !== '');
                const idReg = processedLogs.findIndex((plog) => { return (plog.ip === lineList[2]); });
                if(idReg === -1){
                    processedLogs.push({
                        "ip": lineList[2],
                        "total": parseInt(lineList[4])
                    });
                }else{
                    processedLogs[idReg].total = processedLogs[idReg].total + parseInt(lineList[4]);
                }
            }
        }
        const respLogs = axios.post("http://192.168.1.10:8080/v1.0/saveLogs", {
            processedLogs
        });
        if(respLogs.data.status === "ok"){
                processedLogs = [];
        }
    }
});
```

Log Example (I put in the first line between () the tabulated values that I am considering with used bytes.):

```
1682108440.456 193061 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 (1948251) CONNECT rr7---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vd.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.12.146 -
1682108460.245 356780 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 (6820) CONNECT googleads.g.doubleclick.net:443 - HIER_DIRECT/142.250.200.98 -
1682108460.541 150138 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 (438163) CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108464.239 774102 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 9023 CONNECT outlook.office365.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/52.97.202.66 -
1682108483.598     64 10.1.1.250 TCP_MISS/204 259 GET http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204 - HIER_DIRECT/142.250.200.99 -
1682108483.654    121 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1046 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/142.250.200.132 -
1682108503.723     18 10.1.1.250 TCP_MISS/204 259 GET http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204 - HIER_DIRECT/142.250.200.99 -
1682108503.858    153 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1046 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/142.250.200.132 -
1682108510.532  49938 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 760807 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108554.652  53775 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1582767 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108560.640  59765 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1918167 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108560.708   1788 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 486178 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108585.669  17227 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2236517 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108585.780  24016 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2369434 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108601.625 305048 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 2864938 CONNECT rr6---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2ve.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.209 -
1682108601.704 305121 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1462208 CONNECT rr6---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2ve.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.209 -
1682108610.742  23882 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 1982328 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108610.811  19717 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 153970 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
1682108635.776  23897 10.1.1.250 TCP_TUNNEL/200 563131 CONNECT rr1---sn-2vgu0b5auxaxjvh-v2vz.googlevideo.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/195.8.11.172 -
```